# Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}' in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

There are numerous array values in the itemData[items] array. Although I'm attempting to insert array values, it gives The type {} does not have a property called "length."

```
const searchQuery: SearchFilter[] = [];

for (let items in itemData) {
        console.log(itemData[items]);
        for (var i = 0, len = itemData[items].length; i < len; i++) {
           searchQuery.push({ name: items, value: itemData[items][i] } as SearchFilter);
      }

    }
```

Comment: what does `itemData` look like? Could you add it to your question please.

Comment: Can you share the log data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the variable `itemData[items]` is not an array but an object (the error tell you `exist on type '{}'`).

You can for example count the number of properties of the object:

```
for (var i = 0, len = Object.keys(itemData[items]).length; i < len; i++) {
}
```

`Object.keys()` will return an array of the properties name of your object. You can then get the length of the array with `.length`